# deleting a key value pair in nested dictionary and finding the sum of key values

Tags: python

```
qualifier_2 = {'KKR' : {'Chris Lynn': 4, 
                      'Sunil Narine': 10, 
                      'Gautam Gambhir (c)': 12, 
                      'Robin Uthappa (wk)': 1, 
                      'Ishank Jaggi': 28, 
                      'Colin Grandhomme': 0,
                      'Suryakumar Yadav': 31,
                      'Piyush Chawla': 2,
                      'Nathan Coulter-Nile': 6,
                      'Umesh Yadav': 2,
                      'Ankit Rajpoot': 4,
                      'Extra runs': 7,
                      'Total batted': 10},
                'MI': {'Lendl Simmons': 3,
                      'Parthiv Patel (wk)': 14,
                      'Ambati Rayudu': 6,
                      'Rohit Sharma (c)': 26,
                      'Krunal Pandya': 45,
                      'Kieron Pollard': 9,
                      'Extra runs': 8,
                      'key-valueal batted': 6}
              }
```

this is the nested dictionary, I want to remove a certain key value pair and I want the sum of all the scores.

Comment: I want to write this function which takes dictionary and team as input and returns the total score :print(total_runs(qualifier_2, 'KKR')) should print 107, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Removing a key/value pair:**

```
key_to_remove = 'Krunal Pandya'

for key in qualifier_2:
    inner_dict = qualifier_2[key]
    if key_to_remove in inner_dict:
        del inner_dict[key_to_remove]
        break
```

**Summing of key values:**

```
total = sum([val for outer_key in qualifier_2 
                     for __, val in qualifier_2[outer_key].items()])
```

---

*Testing removing:*

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(qualifier_2)        # after removing 'Krunal Pandya'
```

*Output:*

> ```
> {'KKR': {'Ankit Rajpoot': 4,
>          'Chris Lynn': 4,
>          'Colin Grandhomme': 0,
>          'Extra runs': 7,
>          'Gautam Gambhir (c)': 12,
>          'Ishank Jaggi': 28,
>          'Nathan Coulter-Nile': 6,
>          'Piyush Chawla': 2,
>          'Robin Uthappa (wk)': 1,
>          'Sunil Narine': 10,
>          'Suryakumar Yadav': 31,
>          'Total batted': 10,
>          'Umesh Yadav': 2},
>  'MI': {'Ambati Rayudu': 6,
>         'Extra runs': 8,
>         'Kieron Pollard': 9,
>         'Lendl Simmons': 3,
>         'Parthiv Patel (wk)': 14,
>         'Rohit Sharma (c)': 26,
>         'key-valueal batted': 6}}
> ```

*Testing summing:*

```
print(total)        # with original qualifier_2
```

*Output:*

> ```
> 234
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the fastest solution, without loop:

```
summ_KRR = sum(qualifier_2['KKR'].values()) # sum of 'KRR'
sum_all = sum(map(lambda x: sum(qualifier_2[x].values()),qualifier_2.keys())) # all sum 
qualifier_2.pop('KKR', None) # delete 'KRR'
print('sum:{}'.format(summ_KRR))
print(qualifier_2)
```